# apex.submit does not cause Interactive Grid refresh

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

On my page I am calling `apex.submit("PROCESS1")` from javascript. It executes the code of `PROCESS1` process but the IG I have on the page does not get refreshed. After `PROCESS1` executes I see the unchanged data in the grid and it only changes after I manually refresh the page. My understanding was that submit should refresh the IG on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the behaviour you described. I created an IG on the emp table and a button with name "PROCESS".

- I opened the page with the IG
- In a separate SQL Commands window I updated a single row in the emp table.
- Then in the IG page, in the chrome dev tools console, I executed

```
apex.submit("PROCESS")
```

The page refreshes and the IG re-renders and shows the updated data. This is on 22.2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like this, to explicitly tell it to A)lways refresh?

```
apex.submit( {
    request: "PROCESS1",
    reloadOnSubmit: "A",
} );
```

I found the reference here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/apex.page.html#.submit