# Oracle APEX: IG does not get refreshed after Submit Page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a DA that runs on `Dialog Close` and it performs some actions on the records selected in the IG. Last action in that DA is `Submit Page` action that displays success message. The issue is that the data in the IG does not get updated until page is manually refreshed.

I tried to add region refresh action before submit page action but that made no difference. What else can I try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apex.submit does not cause Interactive Grid refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75581143/apex-submit-does-not-cause-interactive-grid-refresh)

Comment: You asked the same question a while ago. It got 2 answers but no reaction. What has changed ?

Comment: I used apex.submit before now I am using Submit Page. Different code, different question.

Comment: And no, that did not answer my question and the suggestions did not work

Comment: Could you explain how to reproduce or post a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com ? Without knowing exactly what you're doing it's pretty hard to answer